# Appending linear ring to multipolygons in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to append linear ring to multipolygon.
When I try to do same for polygon it works.

case 'Polygon':

```
linearRing=new ol.geom.LinearRing(...);

select.getFeatures().getArray()[0].getGeometry().appendLinearRing(linearRing);
```

case 'MultiPolygon':

```
linearRing=new ol.geom.LinearRing(...);
select.getFeatures().getArray()[0].getGeometry().getPolygon(0).appendLinearRing(linearRing);
```

it's not throwing error, but still coordinates of created linearRing are not appended to selected feature..

Comment: The polygon with linearRing is created but it's not updated on map , I should remove existing polygon and append newly created, is there other and simpler way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multipolygon is defined by an array of polygon coordinates, it isn't a collection of polygons so what is returned by `getPolygon()` or `getPolygons()` should be regarded as clones.

You could either push the linear ring coordinates into the appropriate polygon coordinates and build a new multipolygon

```
var feature = select.getFeatures().getArray()[0];
var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
coordinates[0].push(linearRing.getCoordinates());
feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(coordinates));
```

or append the linear ring to the polygon then append each polygon clone to a new empty multipolygon

```
var feature = select.getFeatures().getArray()[0];
var polygons = feature.getGeometry().getPolygons();
polygons[0].append(linearRing);
var multiPolygon = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon([]);
polygons.forEach(function(polygon){
  multiPolygon.appendPolygon(polygon);
});
feature.setGeometry(multiPolygon);
```

The same applies to line strings returned by `getLineString()`/`getLineStrings()` from a multilinestring.